# org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Path expected for join

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, join, hql

I have problem with `hql`
I have 3 tables
1. users (user_id = pk, username) 
2. groups (group_id = pk, group_name) 
3. usergroups (user_id = fk, group_id = fk)

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="com.model.authRole.UserGroups" table="user_groups" catalog="db_realm" optimistic-lock="version">
    <composite-id name="id" class="com.model.authRole.UserGroupsId">
        <key-property name="userId" type="int">
            <column name="user_id" />
        </key-property>
        <key-property name="groupId" type="int">
            <column name="group_id" />
        </key-property>
    </composite-id>
    <many-to-one name="groups" class="com.model.authRole.Groups" update="false" insert="false" fetch="select">
        <column name="group_id" not-null="true" />
    </many-to-one>
    <many-to-one name="users" class="com.model.authRole.Users" update="false" insert="false" fetch="select">
        <column name="user_id" not-null="true" />
    </many-to-one>
    <property name="aktiv" type="boolean">
        <column name="aktiv" not-null="true" />
    </property>
</class>
```

I want to show username and `group_name` but error from `hql`

```
from UserGroups  ug 
inner  join  Users  u on u.user = ug.user_id
inner  join  Groups g on g.group = ug.group_id
```

and log error

> org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: **Path expected
>   for join!** [from com.model.authRole.UserGroups  ug  inner  join 
>   Users  u on u.user = ug.user_id inner  join  Groups g on g.group =
>   ug.group_id]

How to fix it ?

Comment: Please post users and groups class

Answer (score 0):

I assume that Class `UserGroups` contains object from `User` and object from `Group` Classes

```
session.createQuery("from UserGroups ug where ug.User = :user and ug.Group =:group").setParameter("user", (Users)session.get(Users.class,user_id)).setParameter("group", (Groups)session.get(Groups.class,group_id));
```